# Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null laravel8

Tags: laravel-8

i want fetch two tables data using with() but getting error as "**Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null** "

I have author model with multiple post relationship

My model relation as follows as follows:

Post relationship :

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function author(){
        $this->belongsTo(Author::class);
    }
}
```

Author model as follows:

```
class Author extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function post(){
       return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
    
}
```

my migration of post table as follows:

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('cat');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('author_id');
            $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('authors');
        });
```

I am trying to fetch data in controller as follows using with() in postcontroller

```
public function index(){
        return $data = Post::with('author')->get();
        
    }
```

But getting error as **Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null** . Anyone have idea what is wrong in that then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding a return statement;

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function author(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Author::class);
    }
}
```